# Java ClassNotFound Exception while bulk loading data into HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to bulk load a sample data into HBase table using Java code I found at [this    link](https://github.com/Paschalis/HBase-Bulk-Load-Example).
Although I have included the `guava-11.0.2.jar`, I am getting this error and my program is failing:

```
14/08/19 18:59:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408181320_0291_r_000000_2, 
Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.primitives.Longs
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1541)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1523)
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.KeyValueSortReducer.reduce(KeyValueSortReducer.java:41)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.KeyValueSortReducer.reduce(KeyValueSortReducer.java:35)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I have just started programming in Java. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Which version of hbase are you using?

Comment: I am using version hbase-0.94.22 with apache hadoop 1.2.1...can this be related to the hbase version ?